# Prevent a group of user access Shared Document using csom

Tags: sharepoint, csom

I want to prevent a group of user in sharepoint (Ex: Member) having access to "Shared Documents" by using csom.
However, It doesn't work when I excute my code (The account which are in the group i mention above still have access in my site.
There is my code:

```
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("https://example.com/sites/Litware");
            SecureString password = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in "abcd".ToCharArray()) password.AppendChar(c);
            context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("example@example.onmicrosoft.com", password);
            var web = context.Web;
            context.Load(web);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            var memGroup = web.SiteGroups.GetByName("Member");
            context.Load(memGroup);            
            var users = memGroup.Users;
            context.Load(users);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            foreach (var user in users)
            {
                Principal principal = web.EnsureUser(user.LoginName);
                var folder = web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl("/Shared Documents");
                var roleDef = context.Site.RootWeb.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(RoleType.None);                               
                var roleBindings = new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection(context) { roleDef };
                folder.ListItemAllFields.BreakRoleInheritance(true, false);
                folder.ListItemAllFields.RoleAssignments.Add(principal, roleBindings);
            }
```

So where did I get it wrong and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer the following code:

```
Folder folder = ctx.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/dev/shared%20documents");
ctx.Load(folder);
ctx.Load(folder.ListItemAllFields);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
Group groupToRemove = ctx.Web.SiteGroups.GetByName("dev Members");
ctx.Load(groupToRemove);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
folder.ListItemAllFields.BreakRoleInheritance(true, false);
folder.ListItemAllFields.RoleAssignments.GetByPrincipal(groupToRemove).DeleteObject();
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Reference:

[Remove specific user permissions from one folder in Sharepoint online with powershell](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/248736/remove-specific-user-permissions-from-one-folder-in-sharepoint-online-with-power)